# App "lost property office" with ViewPager, Fragment, ListView, JSON

Tags: android, json, listview, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

I'm doing a lost property office application. It consists of **four tabs**, each tab must display announcement feed uploaded by users. By clicking on a particular item opens a new activity to derive more information.(Well, sort of news feed). I take the data from the API site in the form of **JSON**. 
    I did four tabs using **ViewPager, Fragment.** [image my fragments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCaeZ.png)
    I have tried to place every Fragment listview and display their data with JSON with AsynTask. And caused AsyncTask for  each fragment also called the same JSON in the first fragment. May be it is not right.
    So, please tell me the correct move.

1. *What used to for display data into listview from json*
2. *How to display information on a new activity that opens when you press the listview item?*
3. *Send to fragment over the intent or download a JSON again?*
4. *How to realize adding ads by user?*

If possible, write the steps. Thank you very much, I will be glad of any help.
P.S Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use a simple list adapter to be able to put JSON data into a listview, you can see a tutorial of this [here](http://techlovejump.com/android-poplulating-list-view-from-json/).

Second to be able to see details about a item in a list view you can use a `onListItemClick`, with extending ListActivity. An example of doing this would be:

**MyListActivity.java**

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
// . . .

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         //handle the list click here
         intent = new Intent(this, ListDetails.class);
         //convert the position int into a string to pass to the intent
         value = String.valueOf(position);
         //put the value into the intent
         intent.putExtra("key", value);
         //start the activity here
         MyListActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
     }
}
```

**ListDetails.java**

```
public class ListDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         //gets the value sent with the intent
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         final String helpView = intent.getStringExtra("key");
         // . . .
}
```

This is assuming that you are using a ListActivity to make the list and it really depends on what sort of information you want to display, if you want to display all the data, you could pass the JSON data as a string through the intent, then get it like in the example above.

Thirdly if you want to keep the JSON data you can just pass it along with the intent and then when the user presses back, just pass it back to the original activity once again through the intent. If you want to re-download the JSON data, you can, but to save with users mobile internet connection going over (especially for large JSON files repeatedly), in would not recommend using this option. If you want to download the JSON data again, you will need to use a AsyncTask to download the data, so not to disrupt the user interface and that it will raise a error when you try to do this (believe me, I have pulled my hair out over this). A example of a AsyncTask is (from the android project I am working on, that uses google maps to calculate a route):

```
private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";
        try {
            HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
            data = http.readUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.i("Log","Parser Task Started");
        Log.i("Log",result);
        new ParserTask().execute(result);
    }
}

private class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
        //process the JSON data here
    }
}
```

You would place this inside a activity, adding in the necessary processing for the JSON data inside the onPostExecute in ParserTask. To download the JSON data, you would call (replacing the url with your url for getting the JSON data):

```
String url = "http://www.example.com"
ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
downloadTask.execute(url);
```

**EDIT:**
Lastly to show the latest or most important/relevant lost property adverts, you can once again use JSON to get this from your backend website. In PHP you can customise server responses, sending back JSON responses depending on values in the GET (?thisIsTheGet=blahblahblah). To add advertisements you can create a seperate activity, with EditTexts etc, to create a form, then send the data through a GET request to your backend server (where the JSON is held), so the server can update the advertisement list. Once again you can use a AsyncTask to send the GET request to the server, perhaps using methods above to send back from the server the success of the adding of the advertisement. A example of what your form could look like (XML) would be:

**activity_add_advertisement.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="your.activity.class.root.activityAddAdvertisement"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_advertisement"
    android:id="@+id/LLMainContent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/edittext1"/>
    <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/edittext2"/>
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/submitButton"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then set a on click listener for the button being pressed inside the activity:

**activityAddAdvertisement.java**

```
public class activityAddAdvertisement {
    // . . .
    Button submitButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // . . .
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                   //call the methods from above to send a request to a url, with the contents of the edit texts in the GET request
              }
    }
}
```

You can add more EditTexts and other elements and inside the contents inside the GET request. The server will then edit the JSON to include the new advertisements. The PHP won't be too hard, if you need some tutorials on PHP, W3Schools has good tutorials and examples for you to use.

Further Reading:
[Android Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

What about Volley.

Comment: I make a mobile application of  website where users add themselves advertisement. For example, if they have found what is missing things, documents. And other users can view this advertisement. So, I need to implement the addition of advertisement